# eigenvalues of sum of matrices with algebraic integers eigenvalues

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, algebraic-number-theory

Let $A, B$ be two matrices such that they both have all eigenvalues in $\mathbb{A}$, the ring of algebraic integers.
The question is: it is true that the matrix $A+B$ does have all of its eigenvalues in $\mathbb{A}$?

I couldn't come out neither with a proof nor with a counterexample.

Comment: **Hint:** The first thing to note is that having eigenvalues that are algebraic integers (or even rational integers) does not guarantee that all the matrix entries are algebraic integers.

Comment: Thanks. I think i've found a counterexample: $\left( \begin{array}{cc} 0 & a \\ 0 & 0 \end{array} \right) + \left( \begin{array}{cc} 0 & 0 \\ b & 0 \end{array} \right) $. Both matrices have only zeros as eigenvalue but if for example I set $a = b = \pi$ their sum has not algebraic integer eigenvalues.

Comment: Yes, I had a similar example in mind.  I suggest you write-up your example as an Answer, supplying a bit more detail than given in the Comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so i'm writing the counterexample i've come up with as an answer.

Consider the two parametric matrices $A_a = \left( \begin{array}{cc} 0 & a \\ 0 & 0 \end{array} \right)$ and $B_b = \left( \begin{array}{cc} 0 & 0 \\ b & 0 \end{array} \right)$: they both have algebraic integer eigenvalues (their only eigenvalue is zero, since their characteristic polynomials are, respectively, $p_{A_a}(t) = t^2$ and $p_{B_b}(t) = t^2$), but their sum $C_{a,b} = \left( \begin{array}{cc} 0 & a \\ b & 0 \end{array} \right)$ doesn't always, since its characteristic polynomial is $p_{C} (t) = t^2-ab$.

So if we set, for example, $a = b = \pi$, then the roots of $p_C$ are $t = \pm \pi$ which are not even algebraic over $\mathbb{Q}$.